# Excluding dependency from implementation files

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a jar that I am including in my Android project using the following syntax

```
implementation files('lib/fm.liveswitch.jar')
```

fm.liveswitch has a dependency of org.bouncycastle that I am already including as a dependency of my project. How do I exclude bouncycastle from being included as part of the jar?

I have already tried each of the following:

```
implementation (files('lib/fm.liveswitch.jar')) { 
exclude group: 'org.bouncycastle' 
}

implementation (files('lib/fm.liveswitch.jar')) { 
exclude module: 'org.bouncycastle' 
}

implementation (files('lib/fm.liveswitch.jar'), { 
exclude group: 'org.bouncycastle' 
})

implementation files('lib/fm.liveswitch.jar') { 
exclude group: 'org.bouncycastle' 
}
```

But each time I get an error similar to the below:

```
Could not find method exclude() for arguments [{group=org.bouncycastle}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency
```

Answer (score 4):

When you add file based dependencies, they have no dependency metadata and thus no transitive dependency information.

Given this, there is no point in trying to add an exclude.

Adding `implementation files('lib/fm.liveswitch.jar')` will only add `fm.liveswitch.jar` on the classpath, nothing else.

Now if that JAR contains some bouncycastle classes inside, it is a different story. Gradle has no direct way of letting you control the visibility of the contents of a JAR.

You would then have two options:

- Since it is a local JAR, you can yourself remove the offending classes from it.
- You could attempt to leverage [artifact transforms](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/artifact_transforms.html)